# How to display (inline) LaTeX commands properly?

Tags: formatting, verbatim

When writing about LaTeX, I tend to use `\verb`, which could look like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \verb+\documentclass{article}+
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Thus I get the following result:

[image: Output]

Is there another way to display LaTeX commands properly in continuous text or atleast some way to prevent `\verb` from going over the end of the line?

(For longer code I obviously would use something like `listings`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) package provides lots of commands, including the `\lstinline[<options>]!code!`, and in particular, you can use

```
\lstinline[breaklines=true]!\documentclass{article}!
```

[image: screenshot]

A complete MWE follows- you can explore global settings using `\lstset` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lstinline[breaklines=true]!\documentclass{article}!
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, for I am using this somewhat regularly I put the option `breaklines=true` in the preamble to `\lstset`, which works like a charm.

Comment: @ChristianR. glad it works :)